In reference to Daniel 9 v 24, how was the Most Holy Place anointed and by whom?
To finish the transgression, to put an end to sin, and to atone for iniquity, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal both vision and prophet, and to anoint a most holy place
Daniel 9:24 NIV

“Seventy ‘sevens’ are decreed for your people and your holy city to finish transgression, to put an end to sin, to atone for wickedness, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal up vision and prophecy and to anoint the Most Holy Place.


Thank you for acknowledging my answer. I was one of your "up" voters by the way, or maybe you already surmised that. If you haven't already dug deep on this answer of mine, you really should. You will find it intriguing. Of that I have little doubt.

In reference to Daniel 9 v 24, how was the Most Holy Place anointed and by whom?
"70 Weeks" Prophecy Timeline
It has been well established by many a theologian - at least as to the start of the "70 Weeks" -  and even concurred with by a number of BHSE members, including myself, that Daniel's "70 Weeks" (490 years) prophecy commenced in the year 458 BC, in the 7th regnal year of Artaxerxes I. Nisan 1, to be exact (April 8th Julian, which is April 3rd Gregorian) - see Ezra 7:7-9. This means that the end of the "69th Week" (483 years), when using the astronomically correct years, of 365.2422 days per year, would have ended in Nisan of 26 AD, with the "70th Week" ending (if running concurrently) on  April 5th Julian, April 3rd Gregorian, Nisan 16 Judean (Sunday), of 33 AD, the Resurrection of Jesus Christ, which would make the previous Friday the day of the cross. For a much deeper analysis of this timeline, you can always check out my Q and A here as follows: How can we know WHEN Jesus became "Messiah the Prince" as per Dan, 9:25. Was it at his baptism; arrival on a donkey; or at his death? with links to Rodger C Young's analysis (a latter day bible truth analyst, hailing from St. Louis, MO), entitled - The Theological Problem Presented By The Exactness Of Daniel's 70 Weeks - who then links to one Derek Walker (an Oxford, England, pastor) in his (Young's) footnotes of P. 1, who in turn has an interesting take on John the Baptist being the first part of the Messiah the Prince analogy.
Six Points of Finality in Dan, 9:24
These "Six points of Finality", with out much doubt, have not only to refer to Jesus, himself, but must surely come about at his death and resurrection, with the final point: "Anoint the Most Holy Place" coming into fruition at his Ascension, to the heavenly Holy of Holies tabernacle, where he takes up his seat at the right hand of God, himself.

This is a useful answer, +1

The question is complicated by the fact that "Most Holy Place" can also be translated as "holy of holies" and it is not certain here if it refers to a place or a person (see footnote to 9:24 here). An example of "most holy" applied to persons is found in 1 Chron. 23:13

13 The sons of Amram were Aaron and Moses. Aaron was set apart to be
consecrated as most holy, he and his sons forever, to offer sacrifice
before the Lord, to minister to him, and to bless in his name forever.

Keeping this in mind, the context of this passage can be read as referring either to an anointed high priest or an anointed king, as well as to the sanctuary.

24 Everlasting justice will be introduced,
vision and prophecy ratified,
and a holy of holies [most holy one] will be anointed. 25  Know and understand: From the utterance of the word
that Jerusalem was to be rebuilt Until there is an anointed ruler,
there shall be seven weeks.

The Hasmonean high priest? This interpretation makes particularly good sense in light of the Maccabean hypothesis, which states that Daniel was written in support of the revolt that established the Hasmonean dynasty. In the Hasmonean era the high priest exercised governmental as well as religious authority. In other words, from this viewpoint, the "most holy one" and the "anointed ruler" (sometimes translated as "messiah") would be one in the same person.
Rededication ceremony: On the other hand, if the prophecy indeed refers to the Temple rather than a holy person, then it could point to the rededication of the Temple under Judah Maccabee, which is the origin of the Hanukkah story. Because the the Temple had been desecrated by the Greek ruler Antiochus Epiphanes, it had to be cleansed and rededicated. The prophecy could thus refer to the rededication ceremony as an "anointing" in the sense that it was consecrated or "set apart." This could be symbolic rather than literal, but a physical anointing of this type may be seen in Genesis 28:18:

Early the next morning Jacob took the stone that he had put under his
head, set it up as a sacred pillar, and poured oil on top of it.

Conclusion: The anointing of the holy of holies could refer either to a holy person such as the high priest and/or the ruler mentioned in Dan. 12:25; or to the rededication of the Temple after its desecration.
